# java.lang.NumberFormatException for string values

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, numbers, format

i have a issue making a SQLite edition, basicly, the error is java.lang.NumberFormatException, im making Long.parseLong in my data, but i dont know why the program continues sending me that error , the code of my first class is next:

```
public class SQLiteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText ecoursename, etopic, ecourse_description, elength, erating, esearch;
Button insert, view, search, edit, delete;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ecoursename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cName);
    etopic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cTopic);
    ecourse_description= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cDescription);
    elength= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cLength);
    erating= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cRating);
    esearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);


    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btInsert);
    view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btView);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSearch);
    edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEdit);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btDelete);


    search.setOnClickListener(this);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    insert.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.btInsert:


        boolean works = true;
        try{
        String course_name = ecoursename.getText().toString();
        String topic = etopic.getText().toString();
        String course_description = ecourse_description.getText().toString();
        String length = elength.getText().toString();
        String rating = erating.getText().toString();

        ecoursename.setText("");
        etopic.setText("");
        ecourse_description.setText("");
        elength.setText("");
        erating.setText("");        

        DBAdapter entry = new DBAdapter (SQLiteActivity.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(course_name, topic, course_description, length, rating);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            works = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Dont Works");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();


        }finally{
            if(works){

        // make click says inserted text
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Works?");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("is Working");
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();

        }

        }

        break;

        case R.id.btView:           

        Intent i = new Intent("com.sqlite.base.data.SQLVista");
        startActivity(i);

        break;

        case R.id.btSearch:
            String s = esearch.getText().toString();
            Long ls = Long.parseLong(s);

            DBAdapter dbase= new DBAdapter(this);

            try{
            dbase.open();
            }catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String bN = dbase.getN(ls);
            String bT = dbase.getT(ls);
            String bD = dbase.getD(ls);
            String bL = dbase.getL(ls);
            String bR = dbase.getR(ls);

            dbase.close();

            ecoursename.setText(bN);
            etopic.setText(bT);
            ecourse_description.setText(bD);
            elength.setText(bL);
            erating.setText(bR);

            break;

        case R.id.btEdit:
            try{
            String eCo = ecoursename.getText().toString();
            String eTo = etopic.getText().toString();
            String eDe = ecourse_description.getText().toString();
            String eLe = elength.getText().toString();
            String eRa = erating.getText().toString();
            String eRow = esearch.getText().toString();
            long eRowl = Long.parseLong(eRow);
            DBAdapter edit = new DBAdapter(this);

            edit.open();
            edit.edit(eRowl, eCo, eTo, eDe, eLe, eRa);
            edit.close();

            }catch(Exception e) {
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Dont Works!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btDelete:
            break;  


    }
}
}
```

my DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter {

public static final String ID_ROW = "_id";
public static final String ID_COURSENAME = "course_name";
public static final String ID_TOPIC = "topic";
public static final String ID_DESCRIPTION = "course_description";   
public static final String ID_LENGTH = "length";
public static final String ID_RATING = "rating";

private static final String N_DB = "Clases";
private static final String N_TABLE = "Courses";
private static final int VERSION_DB = 1;

private DBHelper nHelper;
private final Context nContext;
private SQLiteDatabase nDB;



private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, N_DB, null, VERSION_DB);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + N_TABLE + "(" + ID_ROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ID_COURSENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_LENGTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_RATING + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + N_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);           
    }

}

public DBAdapter (Context c){

    nContext = c;
}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    nHelper = new DBHelper(nContext);
    nDB = nHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    nHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String course_name, String topic, String course_description, String length, String rating ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //insert data
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(ID_COURSENAME, course_name);
    cv.put(ID_TOPIC, topic);
    cv.put(ID_DESCRIPTION, course_description);
    cv.put(ID_LENGTH, length);
    cv.put(ID_RATING, rating);

    //return content in table
    return nDB.insert(N_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String receive() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c = nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(ID_ROW);
    int cName = c.getColumnIndex(ID_COURSENAME);
    int cTopic = c.getColumnIndex(ID_TOPIC);
    int cDescription = c.getColumnIndex(ID_DESCRIPTION);
    int cLength = c.getColumnIndex(ID_LENGTH);
    int cRating = c.getColumnIndex(ID_RATING);

    //loop
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(cName) + " " + c.getString(cTopic) + " " + c.getString(cDescription) + " " + c.getString(cLength) + " " + c.getString(cRating) + "\n ";

    }

    return result;
}

public String getN(Long ls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c =nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, ID_ROW + "=" + ls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String ns = c.getString(1);
        return ns;
    }

    return null;
}

public String getT(Long ls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c =nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, ID_ROW + "=" + ls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String ts = c.getString(2);
        return ts;
    }

    return null;
}

public String getD(Long ls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c =nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, ID_ROW + "=" + ls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String nd = c.getString(3);
        return nd;
    }

    return null;
}

public String getL(Long ls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c =nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, ID_ROW + "=" + ls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String nl = c.getString(4);
        return nl;
    }

    return null;
}

public String getR(Long ls) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_COURSENAME, ID_TOPIC, ID_DESCRIPTION, ID_LENGTH, ID_RATING};
    Cursor c =nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, ID_ROW + "=" + ls, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String nr = c.getString(5);
        return nr;
    }

    return null;
}

public void edit(long eRowl, String eCo, String eTo, String eDe,
        String eLe, String eRa) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cvEdit = new ContentValues();
    cvEdit.put(ID_COURSENAME, eCo);
    cvEdit.put(ID_TOPIC, eTo);
    cvEdit.put(ID_DESCRIPTION, eDe);
    cvEdit.put(ID_LENGTH, eLe);
    cvEdit.put(ID_RATING, eRa);
    nDB.update(N_TABLE, cvEdit, ID_ROW + "=" + eRowl, null);

}}
```

really would appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your screenshot.Could you please improve your code to this:

```
}catch(Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage(); //instead of String error = e.toString();
...
```

So we can see the actual cause.
Can you please make the "don't works" dialog large? I think some text is being trimmed.

I believe you are trying to parse an empty string "".